# Where can I find more keys to progress through the Water Temple?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I am on my second or third playthrough of the game, but it's been a long while since I played the entire game through in a long time. I have just gotten to the water temple and used my keys in the wrong order, instead of opening two consecutive doors, I opened only the doors to the room with keese at the entrance and platforms with hookshot targets, and the room that leads to the high level water rise switch. I havn't beaten Dark Link to get the longshot, so I still have the hookshot. I have both the map, the compass and the Biggoron Sword. Is there a way to work around my problem, or do I need to restart the game? I have gotten the key you get when you defeat the four spiked balls, and the key you get by opening the gate with two clams behind it and going into the room beyond. It would be very helpful I someone could provide information on the locations and how to get each of the keys in the dungeon.

Comment: Zelda games are pretty good about preventing you from getting stuck like that, but unfortunately I don't remember the water temple very well.  The only thing I would suggest, is making it more clear what you did once you entered the water temple.  So any keys and items you have gotten from the dungeon.

Comment: Maybe if you could say which keys you have used where (i.e. what room you obtained each key in and where at did you use each key) then it would be much easier to assist you in how to move forward.

Comment: Your scenario rings a bell for me, but I'm pretty sure that there was just a key that I hadn't yet found at that point.  I'm pretty sure that You can't get stuck in OOT unless you're being really creative

Comment: I found the key I missed, that's why I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get another key you need to go into the bottom of the center room, raise the water, and swim down to the place where the block was, there will be a hole and from there it's straightforward to get another key. Also there is another easily reachable key in the central column. You need to go halfway up and then bomb the part of the wall with a crack in it, which is fairly obvious to see.